# Specify default MaxDegreeOfParallelism in Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

We would like to optionally control the number of "threads" on our parallel loops to avoid overwhelming a web service (for example).

Is it possible to specify a custom `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` on a `Parallel.ForEach` loop, but also to revert to the default value as required? Seemingly zero (0) is an invalid value for `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, whereas I was hoping it could simply mean "ignore".

In other words, can you avoid writing this type of code?

```
int numParallelOperations = GetNumParallelOperations();
if (numParallelOperations > 0)
{
 ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
 options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = numParallelOperations;
 Parallel.ForEach(items, options, i => 
 {
   Foo(i);
 });
}
else
{ 
 Parallel.ForEach(items, i => 
 { 
   Foo(i);
 });
}
```

Comment: The answer is to use negative one (-1) as per remarks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Do you mean `-1` as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): _The MaxDegreeOfParallelism limits the number of concurrent operations run by Parallel method calls that are passed this ParallelOptions instance to the set value, if it is positive. If MaxDegreeOfParallelism is -1, then there is no limit placed on the number of concurrently running operations._

Comment: So just make sure that `GetNumParallelOperations` always returns a value that's greater than or equal to -1. That way, you don't need the conditional. `GetNumParallelOperations` could read the value from a configuration file, and supply a reasonable default if the setting isn't there.

Answer (score 8):

Do you mean `-1` as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The MaxDegreeOfParallelism limits the number of concurrent operations
>   run by Parallel method calls that are passed this ParallelOptions
>   instance to the set value, if it is positive. If
>   MaxDegreeOfParallelism is -1, then there is no limit placed on the
>   number of concurrently running operations.

You can control the **approximate** number of threads like this:

```
// use only (ca) one kernel:
int degreeOfParallelism = 1;
// leave (ca) one kernel idle:
int degreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount - 1;
// use (ca) half of the kernels:
int degreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount > 1 ? 
                          Environment.ProcessorCount / 2 : 1;
// run at full speed:
int degreeOfParallelism =  - 1;

var options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = degreeOfParallelism;

Parallel.For(0, x, options, y => 
//...
```

Comment: Begs the question then, is -1 the same as not setting the option?

Comment: Yes it is. As I understood the question, you want to have a unified call. No? - Also you may need the [options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for other members like the `CancellationToken`..

Comment: What's a unified call? I haven't needed to set the other options for it to work.

Comment: [English MSDN ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a definitive answer as I cannot add a comment due to me only just joining StackOverflow. I don't believe it is possible to do as your asking but I do know that MSDN documentation states that -1 is the parameter which sets an unlimited number of tasks to be ran the the ForEach. From my experience, it is best to leave the CLR to determine how many concurrent tasks will be ran unless you really know what you are doing. The Parallel library is high level and if you needed to really do something like this you should be coding at a lower level and in control of your own threads and not leaving it up to a TaskScheduler or ThreadPool etc but this takes a lot of experimentation to get your own algorithms running effectively.
The only thing I can suggest is wrapping the Parallel.ForEach method to include the setting of your ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallism to cut down on the duplicate code and enable you to add an interface and test the asynchonous code in a synchronous manner.
Apologies for not providing a more positive response!